# Facebook Like-button problem

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm using this code to implement the like button

`<fb:like layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450"></fb:like>`

But when I try to click it the counter is increased for about 1 second and then it goes back to zero again. I can't see on my facebook profile that i've liked something either. Someone have a solution for this?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with app engine, as far as I can tell. Perhaps there's a tag for the facebook SDK?

Comment: Also doesn't appear to have anything to do with django.

Answer (score 1):

As other have mentioned some of your open graph meta tags may be missing or incorrect.  You can valid your page with the Facebook URL Linter:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Pretty handy tool and should help you find out what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem once. If you use Firebug to inspect the request/response you'll probably see that Facebook is returning an error to you.

In my case, I hadn't set up the proper permissions on the Facebook "connect" settings to allow 'like' requests from my domain name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a lot of things in the  part of the website to make this work.

For example, I was missing the fb:admins parameter, part of the OG Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem you are describing has been reported in this bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18591

but has been marked as resolved since yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was also having problems with the facebook like plugins and also heard from people that it is a facebook bug. After searching a lot on gOOgle .... I found a good result and don't think that this is a fb bug.

You will have to add this file into the header of your **website**:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Property of Meta Tags (facebook likes Meta Tags) ==> og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.

Replace "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" with real path to image.

**For Wordpress Users:**

Add the following code in the head of your header file ==>

```
<?php $img= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true); if ($img): ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$img ?>"/>
<? endif; ?>
```

That's all... Hope this will work for you all !! Share your experience ...